# same path with different service names in ingress resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm having some issues when using a path to point to different service names, my ingress resource looks as below

nginx-static service is a nginx container which has static content... I have to load this static content while calling service-1, since both nginx-static and service-1 but I cannot keep the sme same host path.... Please suggest how to correct the below ingress resources...

kindly note static content has lot of files(csv,js,html,directories, files etc)

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
     - http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx-static
              servicePort: 80
          - path: "/"
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: 8989
          - path: "/test1"
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 9001
```

Any expert help is appreciated!!!

Comment: >since both nginx-static and service-1 but I cannot keep the sme same host path.... <-- could you please describe (with examples and URLs) what _Exactly_ you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, requirements from the initial questions aren't'  clear and there were no additional clarifications given. However, I'd like to elaborate on [Burak Serdar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar) answer and add , that Kubernetes Ingress allows you listing  the same path ad port for a multiple services under condition that you are listing these for different hosts.

```
foo.bar.com --|                 |-> foo.bar.com nginx-static:80
              | 178.91.123.132  |
bar.foo.com --|                 |-> bar.foo.com service1:8989
```

you can achieve that scenario with the following config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-static
          servicePort: 80
  - host: bar.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 8989
```

However that would work only if you can split your web site between two hosts.

Hope that helps.
You can check more on [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) on K8s documentation.

Comment: What if want to use the same host and the same path to point to two different services wit the constraint that all GET requests go to service1 and all other requests go to service2?  Can I do that with a regex path?  (It would a good solution when you use the CQRS pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same path pointing to different backend resources. You have to put either your static files or the service into a different path, and rewrite the URL, for instance:

rewrite annotation:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
```

paths:

```
- backend:
     serviceName: nginx-statix
     servicePort: 80
  path: /static(/|$)(.*)
- backend:
  path: /
     serviceName: service1
```

With this, your static content will be exposed under `/static/`, and all `/static/name` will be rewritten as `/name` by the ingress.

More info here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but my Domain will never call this path /static... How to handle such scenario....  Is there any way my ingress path & back-end resource will always executed??

Comment: You have to separate the static stuff from the service calls somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume service1 is like a backend while the nginx-static is the client, in this case, its either you use

1. Host name based routing to route requests using the same path to different services, you just tell your static content to send request to the host name nginx would check the host and route request based on that.
2. You can use a if conditional routing in your nginx ingress to route request based on maybe Referer, you can check your request headers for this.

Host Name Based Routing Example

```
- host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: foo
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: bar.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: bar
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

If Conditional Routing

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <name>
  namespace: <namespace>
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       if ($http_referer ~ ^http?://foo) { proxy_pass http://foo:8080; }
       if ($http_referer ~ ^http?://bar) { proxy_pass http://bar:8080; }
spec:
  ingressClassName: <ingress class name>
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: <default backend>
      port:
        number: 8080
```

Note that the proxy pass should be the service name, the above proxies to services foo and bar in the same namespace as the ingress